# Odd scroll behaviour on Chrome when viewed using a Retina screen

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am experiencing some very odd scroll behaviour on the latest Chrome (48.0.2564.116) when viewed using a Retina screen. Wondering if anyone else has experienced this and has a work around?

JsFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dcfkjyxd/

Its seems to be the box-shadow thats causing the scrollbar offset but I don't understand why.

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
```

**Retina screen**

[image]

**Non Retina screen**

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is actually a chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582358&q=retina%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

you can have a read through this http://cubiq.org/webkit-weird-box-shadow-bug-with-fix

try adding a top and bottom value to your divs.